# Complex Sentence

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, complex-sentences

I am having difficulty figuring out how to draw a syntax tree for the sentence:

"Bill reported that a student asked whether the eclipse would occur."

Im confused on which word is the complementiser (that, whether or would?)

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics SE, Questions regarding drawing a syntax tree is not part of Linguistics SE. Perhaps, you could explain what is your problem regarding this particular sentence and it's syntax tree.

Answer (score 3):

A complementizer converts some phrase (usually an S) into a complement.  In the form of a phrase structure rule,

> Complement -> Complementizer S

In your example, the complementizer "that" converts the S "a student asked whether the eclipse would occur" into the complement "that a student asked whether the eclipse would occur", and the complementizer "whether" converts the S "the eclipse would occur" into the complement "whether the eclipse would occur".

Comment: So there are multiple complementizers in this sentence??

Comment: Yes,  That's what I said.